# Why can't i delete file when i have the file's ownership?

Tags: permissions, chown

As a root user, I created a file in / directory. I can only read this file when logged in as normal user (say A) as expected.I changed the ownership to A.Now A can read as well as write.But when I try to delete it, permission denied message comes.Can anyone explain why?

Comment: Can you post the output of `/usr/bin/stat /yourfile`? That would reduce the amount of guess work.

Comment: @joepd see the link in Jeff's comment.  It's got nothing to do with the files permissions :)

Answer (score 6):

Deleting a file isn't a modification of the file, it's a modification of the directory containing the file.  If you don't have the rights to modify the directory, you cannot remove the file within that directory.